# Printf of long double, unknown conversion type character L

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, gcc-warning

my program is pretty simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long double a = 4.5;
    printf("%Lg", a);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled, there is one warning:

```
warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]|
```

The output in the console is

```
-1.28823e-231
```

The documentation is pretty clear about printing long doubles, it simply states that the correct parameter for this format is L. What am I doing wrong? I'm using codeblocks, mingw32-g++ compiler under Windows 10.

P.S.: cout produces the same output.

Comment: No issues with gcc 6.2.1. Perhaps this compiler doesn't support `long double` conversion for `printf`. You can probably avoid this issue by actually writing C++ code instead of C code, and using the `<<` operator.

Comment: your code compiles fine. I compiled it and output was correct. Try using different compiler

Answer (score 2):

You have a compiler problem:

> mingw uses the Microsoft C run-time libraries and their implementation of printf does not support the 'long double' type. As a work-around, you could cast to 'double' and pass that to printf instead.

Therefore, you need `double double`:

> On the x86 architecture, most C compilers implement long double as the 80-bit extended precision type supported by x86 hardware (sometimes stored as 12 or 16 bytes to maintain data structure alignment), as specified in the C99 / C11 standards (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic (Annex F)). An exception is Microsoft Visual C++ for x86, which makes long double a synonym for double.[2] The Intel C++ compiler on Microsoft Windows supports extended precision, but requires the /Qlong‑double switch for long double to correspond to the hardware's extended precision format.[3]

Instead of `printf()`, use `std::cout` coupled with [`std::scientific`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/), for example:

```
#include  <iostream>
std::cout << "scientific: " << std::endl << std::scientific << a;
```

It is best not to use both `stdio.h` and `iostream` in the same project, as they can sometimes interfere with each other.

PS. On the subject, also available are: `std::hex`, `std::dec` (decimal), `std::boolalpha` (true, false) and more.

Comment: @user16320 scientific: 
4.500000e+00

Comment: is the output of the program, tested on cpp.sh using cpp11 flag. What c++ flags are you using?

Comment: What is a c++ flag? I'm using codeblocks. I'm a noob. I can't even use commandline.

Comment: Okay, I installed some other compiler called mingw w64 and it works even with cout. Problem solved.

Comment: @user16320 See edit if you're the curious type about why you were having problems.

Comment: @user16320 Incidently: A c++ flag simply means a setting that you chose to tell the compiler how to behave a quick google will give you tons of info. Briefly: compiler flags -> c++ standard to use, optimization level, warning level (how verbose to warn). linker flags -> what type of assembly to link together (exe, dll etc). These are settable in codeblocks compiler settings (it handles command line for you)